# Private Internet Access error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I have PIA and it worked just fine on ubuntu 14.xx, ive recently upgraded to 16.04 and have been unable to get the VPN to work, I receive a "TideSDK" error upon startup of computer and upon activation of application. I will provide a screenshot of most recent attempt.

Error typed out: Couldn't load file:/home/jonah/.pia_manager/pia_tray.64/runtime/1.3.2-beta/libtide.so, error: libgnutls.so.26: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[Screenshot of error received at any attempt of running app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svl9C.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

We have a new Beta version available which is well supported on Ubuntu which might work better for you on 16.04. You can [download pia beta from this page](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/21361/desktop-applications-release-v59rc1/p1).

Disclaimer: I am a developer working on PIA software.

### EDIT:

- For Ubuntu, right-click and save [this file](https://privateinternetaccess-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/pub/installers/pia-v59rc1-installer.sh)
- In terminal, navigate to the folder where it is saved and run `sh ./pia-v59rc1-installer.sh`
- This will give you a login pane to enter your credentials. After that, click on the PIA icon on your menu bar to choose your vpn server.

NOTE: For future updates refer to the original link.
NOTE: Original link has downloads for Windows and OSX, too.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 I had to go through openvpn and set it up in the terminal since the GUI didn't work. Today I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and this actual GUI program was the only thing that worked for me.